# Retrieve query_string from hardcoded URL

Tags: php

How can I retrieve the query_string, or the parameters after the '?' in the URL if it was hardcoded, and not sent through from a form?

I would normally use $_GET['name'] to retrieve this data, but since I am looking for a method to retrieve the query when someone has hardcoded by directly typing the query_string into the URL, I am unsure what the 'name' would be to use $_GET.

Is this possible?

Comment: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)

Comment: That _is how_ a GET works. Do it how you planned to. POST is the different one where you need to fetch the values from $_POST

Comment: some what confused, examples please.

Comment: I think he means that if someone's entering the query_string by hand, they might have different fieldnames than the form version.

Comment: hmm, you shouldn't really be accepting any old variable name/value through $_GET. You should be specifying what your app will accept from users.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is you don't know what key the user is going to type in for the `$_GET` parameter. So, you can directly loop through `$_GET` like this:

```
foreach( $_GET as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' => ' . $value . "\n";
}
```

This will print all of the parameters.

Now, if you only want the first GET parameter, you can use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift), like this:

```
$first = array_shift( $_GET);
```

Both methods do not require you to know the key of the parameter beforehand.

Comment: Was going to do this, but found out 
$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

does exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
    echo $key . " : " . $value;
?>
```